# Issue: Datatable Server Side Processing in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I am totally new in Django. I am trying to implement datatable server side processing.I have written some codes in my models.py , views.py and urls.py and followed Datatables official documentation also. But unfortunately I am getting error in my terminal and cant able to figure it out how to fix it.

Here is ,
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from ajax_crud.models import Products
from django.http import  JsonResponse

def product_json(request):
    products_json = Products.objects.all().values('title', 'description', 'price')
    data = list(products_json)
    value = JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    print(value)
    return value
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from ajax_crud.views import product_json

urlpatterns = [
   
    path('json/',product_json,name='json'),
   
]
```

**demo-datatbles.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>List of Products</h1>
        <hr>
        <table id="demo-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>price</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo-table').DataTable( {
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url": "{% url 'json' %}",
            "dataSrc": "objects"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "title" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "price" },

        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My error in terminal.**

```
[03/Sep/2020 05:31:49] "GET /json/?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=title&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=description&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=price&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1599111109862 HTTP/1.1" 200 97
```

Please someone help me to get rid of it. **Help will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: The terminal output you show is not an error - it's just displaying the ajax `GET` [request from DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters),containing the info needed by the server so it can build the correct [response](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) (because your table is using server-side processing). Your Django app needs to process this data and respond accordingly with the next (or first) 10 rows of data (`length=10`).

Comment: @andrewjames ok.. I understood .  But still have no idea how can I implement server side processing using django.I just see the html tables. No data is coming..

Comment: Can you add your JSON to the question? I assume it's the data printed by `print(value)`.

Comment: `[{"id": 1, "title": "Neutrogena Oil-Free Acne Wash, 177ML", "description": "Nice products", "price": 300}, {"id": 2, "title": "Product one hello2", "description": "Notes", "price": 400}]`  here is the

Answer (score 1):

I recommend working on this in two steps:

1. Display the basic data (as if you were not using server-side processing).
2. Add your specific server-side logic.

**Background**

I will assume your application is processing the HTML template correctly, and building a valid URL in this expression: `{% url 'json' %}`.

I will also assume that the response being sent to the HTML page from the ajax request is exactly as follows (i.e. the exact JSON data you provided):

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Neutrogena Oil-Free Acne Wash, 177ML",
    "description": "Nice products",
    "price": 300
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Product one hello2",
    "description": "Notes",
    "price": 400
}]
```

If either of these assumptions is false, then the following will probably not help.

(You can use your browser's console to check that the JSON data response is received in the web page. it F12 to open the browser console and inspect the "Network" tab.)

**Step 1**

We will continue to use `"serverSide": true` for this step - so, do **not** remove it.

Your DataTable definition includes the following line:

```
"dataSrc": "objects"
```

This means DataTables will look in your JSON for an object using that name. But there is no object named `objects` - so no data is found.

Therefore you need to **remove that line** from your template.

But because you are using `"serverSide": true`, there are more changes needed.

Look at the link I mentioned in my comments ([this one](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)). This describes the JSON data you need to pass from the server to DataTables when you respond to the ajax request. There is also an example on the same page ([here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data)).

We can therefore take your JSON and make it conform to that requirement:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 1000,
    "recordsFiltered": 1000,
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Neutrogena Oil-Free Acne Wash, 177ML",
        "description": "Nice products",
        "price": 300
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Product one hello2",
        "description": "Notes",
        "price": 400
    }]
}
```

We have wrapped your data in some additional data, as required for server-side processing. Your data is now in an object named `data` - which is where DataTables expects to find it, to populate the rows of your table. So, we do **not** need to use `"dataSrc": "data"` here - because `data` is the default (expected) value.

In the above example I used values of `1`, `1000` and `1000` - just for testing. You can use these values - and then we will fix them in step 2 below.

So you need to **change your Django logic so that it builds the above JSON** and returns that to DataTables.

**Step 2**

Normally (when you do not use server-side processing), the server sends all its data to DataTables at once. DataTables handles all logic for pagination, filtering, and sorting.

But now, with server-side processing, your Django code will be responsible for all of that work. It will not send all the data - it will only one small subset at a time. This is the power of server-side processing: You don't send all 1,000,000 records to the browser (which would crash it). You send only a small, fast subset for each request.

To do this, Django needs to read the request from DataTables. A request is automatically sent by DataTables whenever the user moves to a new page, or performs a sort operation, or filters the data.

Here is one such request - the one you provided in your question:

```
draw=1
&columns[0][data]=title
&columns[0][name]=
&columns[0][searchable]=true
&columns[0][orderable]=true
&columns[0][search][value]=
&columns[0][search][regex]=false
&columns[1][data]=description
&columns[1][name]=
&columns[1][searchable]=true
&columns[1][orderable]=true
&columns[1][search][value]=
&columns[1][search][regex]=false
&columns[2][data]=price
&columns[2][name]=
&columns[2][searchable]=true
&columns[2][orderable]=true
&columns[2][search][value]=
&columns[2][search][regex]=false
&order[0][column]=0
&order[0][dir]=asc
&start=0
&length=10
&search[value]=
&search[regex]=false
```

I manually [URL-decoded](https://www.urldecoder.org/) the request, to make it easier to read.

This request contains all the information Django needs in order to build the required response.

For example:

```
start=0
length=10
```

This tells you that you need to provide 10 records in the response - and those will be the first 10 records (page 1 has an index of 0).

And this:

```
order[0][dir]=asc
```

This tells you that the data needs to be sorted by column 0 (the first column - `title`) in ascending order.

See [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) for full details.

So, you need to write all this logic in your Django application - to read the request, and then implement the instructions it contains, to build the correct response.

Comment: Thanks buddy .. it helped me a lot and I also able to solve my issue .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this package?
https://pypi.org/project/datatables-server-side-django/

I've used that package to implement datatables server side method